# Average of a DAX measure Power BI

Tags: powerbi, average, dax, measure

I have a Power BI data model containing sensor data measuring people coming in and out of a building. Every time a sensor is triggered, a new row is created containing how many people went in, how many out, and the date and time. My fact table is connected to a separate Date table (day level) and Time table (minute level).

I want to create some aggregations on the data to understand Min, Max, Avg people in the building over a period of time, so I created a measure to give me the Cumulative_in_Building:

```
Cumulative_in_Building = 

calculate(
    sum(FootfallTestData[Net Movement]), 
    filter(
        ALL(Dato[Dato]), 
        Dato[Dato]<=Max(Dato[Dato])),
       filter(
        ALL('Time'[TimePresis]), 
        'Time'[TimePresis]<=Max('Time'[TimePresis])) )
```

Problem is that as I can't use aggregations on measures (only columns). How can I get around this?

[image]

Comment: How do you want to average the data over a given period? Do you want average hourly movement for example?

Comment: Hi Rory, Most important would be to get a daily average. It would also be great to get daily max if possible too. Adam

Comment: I'd suggest binning the data by day using `SUMMARIZE()`, then take an average using `AVERAGEX()`

Comment: Thanks Rory, I'll have a look into Summarize.